# Use currentPlaybackTime with MPMoviePlayerController for mp3 files

Tags: ios, mp3, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have used `MPMoviePlayerController` to play audio and video in my app, now I met an very anxious problem. When I played mp3 file, I can't set `currentPlaybackTime` through it is playing. when I changed the `currentPlaybackTime`, the player stopped and post the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` notification. When I restart the `player`, it played at 0 seconds.

I used `MPMoviePlayerController` because it could stream a file from remote url and I needn't change the player when I play an video instead.

I found that it works for several `mp3` file. but I can't point the difference. Does anyone have any experience? I can't even know if it is an feasible plan.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It appears `currentPlaybackTime` works in the case of videos. Below is the description of the function from Apple Docs.

> For **video-on-demand** or progressively downloaded content, this value is measured in seconds from the beginning of the current item. Changing the value of this property moves the playhead to the new location. For content streamed live from a server, this value represents the time from the beginning of the playlist when it was first loaded.

You can try using `[player setInitialPlaybackTime:xx.xx]`;

Comment: I'm sorry but it sames no effect in my program. Nothing had happened. Does it only use for video? I had seen some document about initialPlaybackTime I don't know what's the meaning of it.